# Remove the unwanted space between button and line swift xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am new to iPhone application development.

[image]

I am designing the app like this. in this design, there are two buttons below to delete button and below to those two button, there is the line. that you are seeing in this picture.

What i want is, i want to add the line below to the delete button when those two buttons are hidden by some condition. if those two buttons visible means, that line should come below to those two button. Not below to the delete button.

I have added the following code in cellForRowAt function of TableView. it is not working.

```
cell.line.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:cell.btnDelete.frame.maxY, width: cell.line.frame.width , height: 1 )
```

Any body can help me to solve this issue.

I have added following code to.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {


    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and

```
    dataTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    dataTable.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

Comment: You are using UITableViewAutomaticDimension so you need _autolayout constraints_ that will determine the cell height.

Comment: @matt i know matt.then why this unwanted space is coming.? Could you please explain?

Comment: lable view height is changing automatically based on text length. that is no problem. the problem raises when those two button is hidden by some condition.

Comment: Hidden buttons still have constraints. When the buttons are hidden, the layout constraints also need to change. Or use a UIStackView which does that automatically. Note that your question contains no autolayout constraints at all. No one knows what you are doing except you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to achieve this using some tricky way.Use **Stack View** Add Show,Hide buttons to one UIView.add all other components to another UIView.Add UIStackView to your custom cell and add constraints like this.

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
 ])
```

set stackView distribution to .Fill.

when you want to show/hide buttons, you can add/remove the arranged subView from tableview cell stackView.If you are show/hide buttons in **cellForItemAt** make sure remove all arranged subviews before add.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        cell.stackView.removeArrangedSubview(cell.viewOne)
        cell.stackView.removeArrangedSubview(cell.viewTwo)

        if isShowBuutons {
            cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(cell.viewOne) //View with All other elements
            cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(cell.viewTwo) //View with buttons
        }else{
            cell.stackView.addArrangedSubview(cell.viewOne) //View with All other elements
        }
    }
```

[image: TableView cell structures]

Comment: hello, i have Updated the view to stackview. and again i found some other issue on this. i asked question in following link. could you please explain it.              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61182965/uitableview-showing-one-item-instead-of-two-items-swift-xcode

Comment: where to add following code.     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
 ])

Comment: add this code in setSelected function If you are creating tableview cell programatically.But seems you are using xib.so add these constraints in xib

Comment: did you check that posted question? is there any problem in it?

Comment: i'm checking it