# UITableview showing one item instead of two items swift xcode

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I found the issue while using the UIStackview inside the UITableviewCell.

Here inside the UIStackView i have added four stackview which will explain in Following images.

The design which i have designed as UITableViewCell

[image]

and the views used in UTableviewCells are given below

[image]

[image]

then i share the complete contraints of this view

[image]

result of this particular constaints is working fine in iphone 8 whereas it is not working on iphone 11 Pro max in simulator. it is showing like below image

[image]

and it is showing only one item in UITableview. actually there are two items in the array.

and i can find the second item when i scroll the tableview. second item shown below

[image]

i am stuck with this problem past three days.Any body can give the solution or where i made mistake.

what i want is,the view should be streched to full width and UITableview should show two items.

Helps will be appreciated.

after adding following code.

```
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
             rootStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
             rootStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
             rootStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
             rootStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
  ])
```

and the UITableview showing like this.

i have added the above code in UITableViewCell class.

[image]
**EDIT**

this is constraint for UITableView

```
Data Table.leading = Safe Area.leading
Data Table.trailing = safe Area.trailing
Data Table.top = Header.bottom+70
Reply view.top = Data Table.bottom
```

EDIT 1:

[image]

UITabbleView showing two items with basic label. this label has description.

Comment: did you add constraints for right and left for your outer view and all all inside view with their respective superview?

Comment: Yes it is added. you can see it in 4th image from top.

Comment: from the images it is difficult to got your problem, but first of all you can change your safearea trailing and leading to superview. and check also adding out view first then go to internal view

Comment: I dont understand. could please explain little further.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/J3ArJTp.png in this section as you are connecting you constraints from safearea, you should change it to superview

Comment: ok let me change it.

Comment: i removed those stuff. now, it's asking for x position on content view. do i need to add just constraint 0,0,0,0 or i need to add leading and trailing space to the safe area.?

Comment: Which one is correct.? and could you tell me why the tableview is showing only one item instead of two items?

Comment: add it to 0,0 to superview trailing and leading

Comment: form images it is difficult so if you can share the code on github then i can help better

Comment: shall i share xib file alone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211530/discussion-between-noorul-and-arun).

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be your table view’s constraint. Trailing and bottom.

Comment: this is the constaint i have for tableview.Data Table.leading = Safe Area.leading
Data Table.trailing = safe Area.trailing
Data Table.top = Header.bottom+70
Reply view.top = Data Table.bottom

Comment: is there anything i need to change?

Comment: Try to remove the last item. I’m not sure. But you can scroll your table view means there is no problem with your cells.

Comment: I can sroll the Tableview. the problem is the view is not filling completely to the trailing space. and the second view is coming to visible the the first item scroll in the same place where the first item was. and it is gone when i scroll down.

Comment: How about create a simple cell with only one label, then fix the layout of table view first. After that you can load your old cell you describe above?

Comment: basic cell is working fine bro. this one make me really bad

Comment: @Noorul clear all constraints and start over. I usually do when thing is too complicated.

Comment: Ok. please give some suggestion about these constraints. Do i need to add the constraints for Content View. so, it will be leading,top,trailing and bottom to safe Area. isn't?

Comment: No need for cell contentview. Its auto-managed by tableview. Your stackview’s layout fit contentview is enough. You may need to research about layout priorities also.

Comment: OK bro. and do you have any idea why only one item is showing first time and second item is showing when we scroll ?

Comment: and if i remove the constraints for Content View, its ask for x and y positions. with red line. what should i give for it. i was just set 0,0,0,0 constraint before.

Comment: @Noorul i’m not sure with your code. Check data source, make simple layout with one stackview and several labels first. Then add more components one by one.

Comment: OK bro. i will do it as first

Comment: i have tested with basic label. i have updated the question. dear sulen -  1st item, Dear Anand  - 2nd item

Comment: @Noorul keep moving bro !